# Message construction interfere

Tags: netty

I bumped to a problem that looks like that: 
 1) I have long messages ~70Kb constructed in the ByteToMessageDecoder - let's call it BlockMessage 
 2) In the meantime there is Timer that does Ping/Pong , 
 that is send Ping and get's a Pong both short ~8 bytes messages.
 (!!!) the problem is that sometimes I see Pong message interfere into BlockMessage and that's breaks the message construction.

can be described like that:

1) I am in the process 
of reading message:

```
@Override
protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception {

    // No header for Eth. message
    if (in.readableBytes() < 8) return;

    long magicBytes = in.readUnsignedInt();
    long msgSize = in.readUnsignedInt();

    if (!((magicBytes >> 24   &  0xFF) == 0x22  &&
          (magicBytes >> 16   &  0xFF) == 0x40  &&
          (magicBytes >>  8   &  0xFF) == 0x08  &&
          (magicBytes         &  0xFF) == 0x91 )) {

        logger.error("abandon garbage, wrong magic bytes: [ {} ] msgSize: [ {} ]", magicBytes, msgSize);
        ctx.close();
    }

    // Don't have the full packet yet
    if (msgSize > in.readableBytes()) {

        logger.debug("msg decode: magicBytes: [ {} ], readBytes: [ {} ] / msgSize: [ {} ] ", magicBytes, in.readableBytes(), msgSize);
        in.resetReaderIndex();
        return;
    }

    logger.debug("message fully constructed go handle it: readBytes: [ {} ] / msgSize: [ {} ]", in.readableBytes(), msgSize);

    byte[] decoded = new byte[(int)msgSize];
    in.readBytes(decoded);

    out.add(decoded);

    in.markReaderIndex();

}
```

2) in the meantime: timer invokes ping and gets pong from the 
peer

3) I get this pong inside the frame in 1)

I think it's a pretty simple and common case, but I didn't find any example and the
question is how to avoid frames interfere ?

P.S. I use:  `4.0.17.Final`

Comment: Can you please give more of a description of how they interfere? .write(..) is designed to handle concurrency.

Comment: Updated the info, is it better now ?

Comment: How are you writing both messages to the channel? Are you writing the large message using a single call to write, or are you fragmenting it? Is your decoder shared between multiple channels? There are few things that could be causing this but, as md_5 says, if you have just two separate calls to write, one for each message, and you're using TCP, this shouldn't happen - the ping should be stuck behind the block message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a root cause and a solution for this:

(Problem) When big message arrives it is constructed to a message
out of byte stream packets. Over that period no other message should
be asked on that channel, and even small ping/pong will interfere
and insert corrupting data into the construction.

(Solution) in order not to interfere, I use queue order 
of the messages and only when the full message been 
received the next round trip is invoked, whether it's a
ping/pong or another request/response.